# Django UnicodeEncodeError on QuerySet extra to PostgreSQL if started from shell

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Hello all
I'm using Django 1.2.5 with Python 2.6 on two machines: Ubuntu 11.04 and Debian Lenny. First one is my local dev and second is remote server. I'm using django-fts and postgresql (database is remote and unique for both installations) to make full text search queries. The intriguing thing is I can do fts query with russian symbols in it on local machine all right. On remote server it gives me UnicodeEncodeError while evaluating my extra.

In django-fts postgre backend I find this code:

```
    ts_query = "plainto_tsquery('%s','%s')" % (self.language, unicode(query).replace("'", "''"))
    where = '%s @@ %s' % (qn(self.vector_field.column), ts_query)
    select = {}
    order = []
    if rank_field is not None:
        select[rank_field] = 'ts_rank(%s.%s, %s, %d)' % (qn(self.model._meta.db_table), qn(self.vector_field.column), ts_query, rank_normalization)
        order = ['-%s' % rank_field]
    return qs.extra(select=select, where=[where], order_by=order)`
```

where query contains u'\u0430' or u"а" (cyrillic) so it encoded in utf-8 all right so far.

Error appears in django/db/models/sql/compiler.py on line 489 while trying to assemble a query from extras:
`result.append('(%s)' % str(col))`

So, I tried all of coding/decoding stuff. LANG variable is "ru_RU.UTF-8" on both computers and in settings.py as DEFAULT_CHARSET. Have no more ideas. Any help?

**UPDATE:** I've just found out that my application executes the same way on both computers. The difference is between execution from shell (python manage.py runserver localhost:8000) and debug-mode start from eclipse's pydev environment. So, can some one tell me if there's difference between manual start and pydev debug start concerning my encoding problems?

TIA.
Petr

Comment: What's the encoding on the Postgres DB?

Comment: UTF8 
I managed to make full text search itself work:

    return qs.extra(where=[where.encode('utf-8'])

does the trick. But if I try to do any extra selects on this QuerySet I keep getting UnicodeEncodeError even if I ensure that every string being added goes through encode('utf-8') expression.

Comment: well, actually this wasn't true: where clause works without specifying any encoding, but select still doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a u'' to all the string in your example.
like u'ts_rank(%s.%s, %s, %d)' % (...)
and also interpolating variables with % without database escape is bad.

Comment: Yeah, Evgeny, I know that. But it was made (I suppose) because making use of params and select_params in extra query somehow breaks quotation of strings. I tried to make to_tsquery(%s, %s) with params =[...] but got to_tsquery(russian, абв) in sql. This isn't right, I need those strings quoted. But if I use it like to_tsquery('%s', '%s'), resulting sql comes with syntax error.

Nevertheless, your answer was helpful, although I printed type() of query elements and all of them were unicode.